# Is there any configuration to stop chunking/bundling css in angular5 app in development mode?

Tags: css, angular, angular5, angular-cli

Is there any configuration to stop chunking/bundling css in angular5 app in development mode

I have very big angular5 app so there are hundreds of css files and I'm not able to identify which css comes from where, so designing gets difficult.

We just moved from angular 4 to 5, it was well in 4 but not in 5, not working for debugging css

is there any angular-cli configuration to stop bundling css, instead it should show file path along with css in debugging?